# Error: can not find android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: xml, layout, widget, toolbar, android-support-library

I want to create a toolbar with the following code:

In **tool_bar.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

In **main_activity.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

An error occurs and tell me that it can not retrieve `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` ...
When I go on the appcompat v7 folder I can not find the `Toolbar.class` on the Widget package. I don't understand because the android support library is up to date. Is that because I am targeting an API below 21 ?

Thanks for your answers.